# How to get path to config file OS-independent way?

Tags: java, configuration, platform-independent

I developing a java application that uses commons configuration for configuring from xml-files. On Linux i want to store these files in folder like /etc/. On Windows it must be a folder like ProgramData//. How to get path to these folders OS-independent way? For example, System.getProperty("user.home") looks good because it works on Windows and Linux, but on windows it returns user home folder, but i need a folder like commonappdata.

Comment: Does the config have to be stored _outside_ the application? You could always add the location to the classpath in a startup script.

Comment: Is storing config inside application means stroing inside .jar? Is it  impossible to write config in this case?

Comment: If you want to store editable, OS independent, settings then avoid using native file paths altogether. This is exactly what the [Java preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) is for.